# Discrepant results: tau coefficient and linear regression

Tags: r, regression, correlation, linear, kendall-tau

I have two continuous variables $x, y$ that are not normal, but whose logarithmic transformations are normal and meet all assumptions for linear regression.

In R, I evaluated their correlation through Kendall's rank coefficient $\tau$ with a result of $\tau \approx -0.40$ ($p<0.001$). I think I am correct in interpreting this value as a moderate, yet significant correlation.

I also applied logarithmic transformations to both variables and ran a linear regression analysis, with a statistically significant result and a slope of $log(x)=-0.10$. Translated back to the terms of the original variable, this result implies that before a $1\%$ increase in $x$ we can expect a $0.1\%$ decrease in $y$. We could also say that, should $x$ increase to twice its value, $y$ should be expected to decrease only $6.6\%$. This second correlation, drawn out of the linear regression, seems very weak.

I am having trouble interpreting this discrepancy. The $\tau$ coefficient indicates a relationship far stronger than that resulting out of the linear regression applied to the transformed variables. What does this mean? Are there reasons to prefer one of the analysis over the other? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The second correlation" is not a correlation, it's a slope.   Consider the equation $\ln y_i = -0.1 \ln x_i$, with no randomness.  The correlation is 100%, and the slope is -0.1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that, I was committing a technical error when interpreting the linear regression's result as a correlation. However, the doubt is still with me. In very simple terms, the tau coefficient says that when $x$ increases $y$ decreases moderately. From the linear regression, we gather that when $x$ increases $y$ decreases very weakly... How are this results not discrepant?

Comment: You are still misunderstanding the Kendall $\tau$.   It doesn't say that when $x$ increases, $y$ decreases moderately - that's what a slope would do.  What it does say, roughly, is that (in this case) larger $x$ tend to correspond to smaller $y$ - but there's no magnitude associated with the change.   The Kendall $\tau$ in my example above would be equal to $-1$, despite the low slope.  Consider $x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, and $y = 10, 20, 30, 40, 50$.   Then consider the same $x$ and $y = 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005$; calculate the slope and the Kendall $\tau$ for both.

Comment: That was completely clarifying. Thank you very much!